# Is it possible to turn of the GSM radio and still use data connection?

Tags: calls, cellular-radio, gsm

I recently starting using a Samsung Galaxy S4. I need to use a special phone at my work. For that purpose I have a duo card where I turn off one phone to use the other.

The problem is that I can only turn off all connections on the Samsung (Airplane Mode), including the mobile internet connection.

My question is: can I turn off the phone capabality (GSM?) on the Samsung while maintaining my mobile network on the Samsung?

Comment: If you have Wi-Fi available you can activate Airplane Mode and then re-activate Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 14):

Simply impossible. Mobile Network **IS** [GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM). GPRS, EDGE, UMTS or LTE, which are different standards for providing *packet-based Internet connections*, are all expansion of the GSM standard and, as such, require a GSM signal.

Comment: I think that sums it up. Thanks for your quick response, Shywim.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you are allowed to divert incoming calls and messages to another number, you can divert them to a number that is disconnected and you will still have the data connection on your phone.